# building dictionaries from a list based on a repeating item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that needs to be grouped every time a duplicate value occurs, the duplicate value being the header of a table.

I'm currently trying to solve this with a series of for loops and I think this is probably a simple enumerate + zip somewhere.

```
items = [
    {
        "0": 'name',
        "1": 'phone',
        "2": 'email'
    },
    {
        "0": "John",
        "1": "8888888888",
        "2": "email@email.com"
    },
    {
        "0": "James",
        "1": "7777777777",
        "2": "email@email.com"
    },
    {
        "0": 'name',
        "1": 'phone',
        "2": 'email'
    },
    {
        "0": "Jim",
        "1": "8888888888",
        "2": "email@email.com"
    },
    {
        "0": "Joe",
        "1": "7777777777",
        "2": "email@email.com"
    },
]
```

Notice that the items 0 and 3 are "headers" and they are the same. I need to group the contacts into a new object. The groups consist of the data between every header. it would look like this:

```
new_items = [
    {
        "group_one": [
            {
                "0": 'name',
                "1": 'phone',
                "2": 'email'
            },
            {
                "0": "John",
                "1": "8888888888",
                "2": "email@email.com"
            },
            {
                "0": "James",
                "1": "7777777777",
                "2": "email@email.com"
            },
        ] 
    },
    {
        "group_two": [
            {
                "0": 'name',
                "1": 'phone',
                "2": 'email'
            },
            {
                "0": "Jim",
                "1": "8888888888",
                "2": "email@email.com"
            },
            {
                "0": "Joe",
                "1": "7777777777",
                "2": "email@email.com"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Then each item after the header in these new lists needs to be combined. Something like:

```
combined_items = [
    {
        "group_one":
            {
                'name': 'John/James',
                'phone': '8888888888/7777777777',
                'email': 'email@email.com/email@email.com'
            }
    },
    {
        "group_two":
            {
                'name': 'Jim/Joe',
                'phone': '8888888888/7777777777',
                'email': 'email@email.com/email@email.com'
            }
    }
]
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
cleaned_dictionaries = []

for row in items:
   if isinstance(row, dict):
      if row.get('0', None) != 'name':
         cleaned_dictionaries.append(row)

header_values = items[0].values()

rows = [dict(zip(header_values, d.values())) for d in cleaned_dictionaries]
```

Which is taking the first object as the header, then iterating through the rest of the list building a list of dictionaries and skipping any object in the list that contains headers.

The problem is that I can't keep my groupings together.

Comment: It looks very much as if you want a data frame manager, such as PANDAS, and the `groupby` facility.  In the meantime, please remember that any coding problem should include the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first group your items with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which will use the headers as `key` to do the splitting:

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

headers = {"0": "name", "1": "phone", "2": "email"}

groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(items, key=lambda item: item == headers) if not k]

pprint(groups)
```

Which will give you these groupings:

```
[[{'0': 'John', '1': '8888888888', '2': 'email@email.com'},
  {'0': 'James', '1': '7777777777', '2': 'email@email.com'}],
 [{'0': 'Jim', '1': '8888888888', '2': 'email@email.com'},
  {'0': 'Joe', '1': '7777777777', '2': 'email@email.com'}]]
```

Then you could iterate these groups, use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group each dictionary by headers, then add the final result to a combined dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

combined_items = {}
for idx, group in enumerate(groups, start=1):
    header_groups = defaultdict(list)

    for dic in group:
        for k, v in dic.items():
            header_groups[headers[k]].append(v)

    combined_items[f"group_{idx}"] = {k: "/".join(v) for k, v in header_groups.items()}

pprint(combined_items, sort_dicts=False)
```

Which gives:

```
{'group_1': {'name': 'John/James',
             'phone': '8888888888/7777777777',
             'email': 'email@email.com/email@email.com'},
 'group_2': {'name': 'Jim/Joe',
             'phone': '8888888888/7777777777',
             'email': 'email@email.com/email@email.com'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

With data like this, you're going to be far better off using `pandas`:

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(items)

In [17]: df.groupby(df['0'].eq('name').cumsum()).agg(lambda x: '/'.join(x[1:])).rename(columns={'0': 'name', '1': 'phone', '2': 'email'})

Out[17]:
         name                  phone                            email
0
1  John/James  8888888888/7777777777  email@email.com/email@email.com
2     Jim/Joe  8888888888/7777777777  email@email.com/email@email.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is a great way to solve it, @RoadRunner just make more sense to me when I write it out.